# Template can't find my named iron-router route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In a meteor project using iron-router, a pathFor in my template can't find a named route. I think I've adhered to the syntax in the [guides](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes).

Here's the spacebars code:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'tag.show' _id=this._id }}" class="tag" id="{{title}}">{{title}}</a>
```

And here's the iron-router code:

```
Router.route('/tags/:_id', function() {
  this.layout('layout');

  this.render('tags');

  this.render('tagDetail', {
    to: 'topDrawer',
    data: function() {
      return Tags.findOne({
        _id: this.params._id
      });
    }
  });
}, {
  name: 'tag.show'
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The exact error in my console is

```
pathFor couldn't find a route named "tag.show"
```

EDIT 2: For kicks, I tried retrieving another simpler route by name:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.go('post.show');
```

And I get an 'undefined' error. I haven't been able to solve this problem.

Comment: Try `{{pathFor 'tag.show' data=this}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no dice! I've been staring at this for a loooong time and I do feel like it must be something obvious.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the route isn't declared properly. What happens if you navigate to it directly?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I get an error (after following cwohlman's answer) that says there's no matching route on the client or server. I used the meteor mongo console to pick up an _id to use in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your declaration backwards, try:

```
Router.route('tag.show', function() {
  this.layout('layout');

  this.render('tags');

  this.render('tagDetail', {
    to: 'topDrawer',
    data: function() {
      return Tags.findOne({
        _id: this.params._id
      });
    }
  });
}, {
  path: '/tags/:_id'
})
```

By the way this may be caused by a change in the iron router api. The version I'm using is 0.9.4 and this is how I declare routes in that version:

```
this.route('home', {path: '/'});
```

Then elsewhere I define a custom controller:

```
HomeController = RouteController.extend({
  // nothing yet
});
```

Comment: It seems like he did it correctly, based on [this section](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#named-routes), but who knows?! I can't recall a time when the IR docs actually matched the code.

Comment: cwohlman's suggestion is progress I think. IR now finds a route without throwing any errors, yet in spacebars each href tag is linking to "/tag.show" now. I'm wondering if I haven't set the path or the params up correctly? I'm relatively inexperienced with Javascript. Could it be that the :_id isn't defined?