# Iron Router named routes can be accessed within meteor shell, but not within client

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Note: I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462846/template-cant-find-my-named-iron-router-route) about this same issue, but without successfully resolving it. As I continue to research and experiment I think I can re-frame it in a simpler way.

Given a route:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  name: 'home'
});
```

I can open the new meteor 1.0.2 shell and try:

```
Router.routes['home']
```

Which successfully returns a result. However, when I go to my console in Chrome and type the exact same thing, I get an undefined.

Why does meteor shell recognize the route, but not chrome console? I've tried removing then re-adding iron:router and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: What is the relative path to the file containing the route definition? Alternatively, do you have a repo I can look at?

Comment: Hi David, router.js is in the root of the project. I put up a repo at https://github.com/aktaplin/pin in case you want to look at the whole thing. This is a learning project for me.